# how to detect outliers in the columns of a dataframe? in R

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

I have a data frame, suppose this:

```
names<-c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")
var1<-c(0.942999593,0.935507266,0.973589623,0.969415912,0.95230801,0.935507266,0.888740961,0.91750551,0.944482672,0.945468585,1.457579147,0.922206277,0.941511433,0.954724791,0.941014244,0.941511433,0.941511433,1.50511433)
var2<-c(-0.012678088,0.014313763,0.001138275,-0.020568206,0.012987126,0.001217192,0.03360358,0.009758172,0.015066932,-0.037879492,0.020471157,0.010738162,0.010952531,0.019377213,0.027140572,0.031116892,-0.018530676,-8.90E-05)
as.data.frame(cbind(names,var1,var2))->df
```

I would like to convert the outliers to Na in the columns var1 and var2. However I would like to calculate the outliers independently for each category in the column "names". So the outliers for "a" in var1, will be the outliers found using just the first 5 rows in var1.

the way in which I detect the outlier is all values, below or above the quantiles 0.25 and 0.75 respectively.

Is there any easy way to do this in R?

thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Comment: You can use `split()` on your `df` by variable `names` and detect your outlayer (however you define it).

Comment: @JuliánUrbano : How could it not?  She asked for quantile values, not absolute numeric values

Comment: @CarlWitthoft right..didn't read that right ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can do it for var1:

```
quantiles<-tapply(var1,names,quantile)
minq <- sapply(names, function(x) quantiles[[x]]["25%"])
maxq <- sapply(names, function(x) quantiles[[x]]["75%"])
var1[var1<minq | var1>maxq] <- NA
```

Repeat the same for var2 (or df$var2).

Comment: What I was going to say, but this is cleaner (note the handy way `minq` matches up with the levels).